# How to display values for office in JSON records via PHP

Tags: php, json

I am trying to display JSON records. I have successfully gotten values for **id, chart_id, first_name**.

My issue is that values for **office** parameters throws error of undefined offset. How do I also print values for offices parameters?

Below is the code:

```
<?php

$output ='
{"previous":null,"results":[
{"id":91168488,"chart_id":"SMAM000001", "offices":[3033],"first_name":"Nancy"},
{"id":91168489,"chart_id":"MADE000004", "offices":[3044], "first_name":"Moore"}]
}
';

$json = json_decode($output, true);

foreach($json["results"] as $v1){
    echo $id = $v1['id'];
    echo "<br><br>";

    echo $chart_id = $v1['chart_id'];
    echo "<br><br>";

    echo $first_name = $v1['first_name'];
    echo "<br><br>";
    
    echo $offices = $v1['offices'];
    echo "<br><br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: echo $offices = $v1['offices'][0];

Comment: maybe `$offices = implode(', ', $v1['offices']);` would do it since it is an array.

Comment: The brackets around `[3033]` in `"offices":[3033]` makes that another array :)

Comment: Thanks everyone. special Thanks to you Stefan. your suggestions works for me. you can update it as the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [3033] is an array, just add `[0]` at the end of `$v1['offices']`

```
echo $offices = $v1['offices'][0];
```